# Need help in rendering a mapbox map in my node.js application

Tags: node.js, mapbox

I want to render a mapbox map such that the surrounding details of the location are also there such that we can get an idea of the location by looking at it. Current it looks like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphUB.png)

--As you can see that only the marker is visible without any of the surrounding details. How to configure the mapbox sdk in a better way for the usecase. If there are any better alternatives do mention them too. -

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    // style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12', // style URL
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
    center: coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 12.5, // starting zoom
});

const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(coordinates)
    .setPopup(
        new mapboxgl
            .Popup({ offset: 25 })
            .setHTML(`<h1>${mapEntity.restaurantName}</h1>`)
    ).addTo(map)

const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav, 'top-left');
```

This is my current configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "surrounding details of the location"? Do you want to show the street names? If so, you need to adjust your layer in mapbox studio. Do you want more markers with nearby shops? If so, you need to add them manually.

Comment: Yes the street names, the surrounding building names so that the place where the marker is present can be identified correctly